# Facebook PHP SDK -No app_data after user app installation

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having an issue with passing `app_data` after a new app install redirect
using the `Facebook PHP SDK`

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'email,manage_pages', 'redirect_uri' => $fbconfig['appPageUrl'], ) );

$decodedSignedRequest = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $fbconfig['secret']); 

if (isset($decodedSignedRequest['app_data'])){
    echo $app_data=$decodedSignedRequest['app_data'];
    header("Location: success.php?id=$app_data");
    die();
}
```

If the app is installed I get `app_data` from the `signed_request` without a problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your Location header is *wrong*, because it requires an *absolute* URL by definition.

And if you append a query string ?id=1234, then you can access that value via $_GET['id'] in your script.

Comment: i will try and explain myself a bit more clearly, if i want to pass the app_data through a link i target someone to install my app for example: https://www.facebook.com/mypage?sk=app_123456&app_data=Install|google, the app_data is a signed_request var which should be passed but isn't after the user installs the application.

Comment: Well then try putting the app_data in your redirect_url.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t really see what/where your problem is. Please update your question with some more details about the flow and what you’re doing where and when.